# Fetch users liked Instagram-images after API update 2016

Tags: api, instagram, self

**Hey!**

After Instagram updated its API on the 1. june 2016 we are not able to get out JavaScript Instagram implementation to work. We inspected the client-setup and noticed that it has been put in Sandbox mode. When trying to resubmit then none of the valid user cases did fit, and we understood that they had removed our rights to fetch other peoples content through the account without getting permission from each individual owner.

As far as i understood, the new parameter "scope" needs to be set to "public_content" and this requires the users permission.

So at the moment the solution below only fetches the users own pictures that is self-liked. Before we also got other peoples images that the user had liked.

So, do anyone know how to fetch liked content of an account post 1. june 2016?
Does getting a Instagram Business account help you for displaying other peoples content?

Here is the code example with an additional filter on the hashtags.
If anyone got a better idea of how to filter on hashtags and liked content at the same time please let me know :)

```
$.fn.instagramFeedInit = function()
{
    if(!$('#instagram-content').length)
    {
        return;
    }
    var container = $('#instagram-content');
    var tag = container.data('hashtag');
    var image_display_count = container.data('image-count');
    var access_token = [INSERT_TOKEN_OR_SOUTH_PARK_REFERENCE_HERE];
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/liked?access_token=' + access_token + '&callback=callback&count=99999',
        jsonp: 'callback',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(response) {
            var container = $('#instagram-content');
            var i = 0;

            // Loops through images
            $(response.data).each(function(i, el){
                // Check that it has correct tag
                if(jQuery.inArray(tag, el.tags) !== -1)
                {
                    var imageTitle = el.caption.text;
                    var image = el.images.low_resolution.url;
                    var refImage = el.images.standard_resolution.url;
                    if (el.type === 'video') {
                        var videoLink = el.videos.standard_resolution.url;
                        container.append('<a class="lightbox instagramimage mfp-iframe"  title="' + imageTitle + '" href="' + videoLink + '" ><img  src="' + image + '"></a>');
                    }
                    else {
                        container.append('<a class="lightbox instagramimage" title="' + imageTitle + '" href="' + refImage + '" ><img src="' + image + '" class="img-responsive"></a>');
                    }
                    i++;
                    // If we have reached maximum display images
                    if(i == image_display_count) return false;
                }
            }); 
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that if you are in Sandbox mode, only post from authorized Sandboxed users will appear in any api requests. Regardless of whether you have the public_access scope.

Note: you need to add `scope=public_access` to your authorization URL now. It's no longer included by default

E.g A and B are both sandbox users C is not.
A likes a post from C.
The liked media endpoint for A will not include the post from C. He is invisible to your sandbox app
A then goes an likes a post from B
The liked media endpoint for A will now include the post from B as he is visible to your sandbox app

Comment: Thanks four your candid answer!

We actually tried to create a new token with the scope-parameter to "public_content", but we get an error because we are still in sandbox mode. To get out of sandbox mode we got to resubmit, be none of the valid usecases fits us. We are hoping to find a way around this with another solution, but so far the future look grim.